# Is it possible to execute multiple "COPY FROM" commands from a file?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, backup, sqlbulkcopy

Via pgAdmin, I created a backup file with the following format:

```
COPY alpha (columns) FROM stdin;
data TAB data TAB ...
data TAB data TAB ...
data TAB data TAB ...
\.

COPY beta (columns) FROM stdin;
data TAB data TAB ...
data TAB data TAB ...
data TAB data TAB ...
\.

COPY gamma (columns) FROM stdin;
data TAB data TAB ...
data TAB data TAB ...
data TAB data TAB ...
\.
```

How can I can read this file into postgres and restore each table?